# Jackrabbit clustering

Tags: jackrabbit

I am using jackrabbit 2.18.0 and I would like have a cluster setup on my local, later on AWS.

Now I am able to run it with one node with the following configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Repository>
    <!-- Enable bellow config for mysqldatastore-->
    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jackrabbit" />
        <param name="user" value="root" />
        <param name="password" value="" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_R_DS_"/>
    </DataStore>
    <!-- Enable bellow config for filedatastore-->
    <!--DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
            <param name="minRecordLength" value="100"/>
        </DataStore-->
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
    </FileSystem>
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleAccessManager" />
        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleLoginModule">
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous" />
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>
    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="jcrlocal" />
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
            <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jackrabbit" />
            <param name="user" value="root" />
            <param name="password" value="" />
            <param name="schema" value="mysql" /> 
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_PM_${wsp.name}_" />
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
        </PersistenceManager>
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>
    </Workspace>
    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
            <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jackrabbit" />
            <param name="user" value="root" />
            <param name="password" value="" />
            <param name="schema" value="mysql" />
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_V_PM_" />
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>

    <Cluster id="node1" syncDelay="5"> 
        <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.DatabaseJournal"> 
            <param name="revision" value="${rep.home}/revision"/> 
            <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jackrabbit"/> 
            <param name="user" value="root"/> 
            <param name="password" value=""/> 
            <param name="schema" value="mysql"/> 
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_C_"/> 
        </Journal> 
    </Cluster> 
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">   
          <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/index"/>
          <!-- SearchIndex will get the indexing configuration from the classpath, if not found in the workspace home -->
          <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="/Users/tuhinsubhramandal/jack-repo/indexing_configuration.xml"/>
          <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true"/>
          <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100"/>
          <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3"/>
          <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="100000"/>
          <param name="mergeFactor" value="10"/>
          <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000"/>
          <param name="bufferSize" value="10"/>
          <param name="cacheSize" value="1000"/>
          <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="false"/>
          <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
          <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl"/>
          <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true"/>
          <param name="resultFetchSize" value="100"/>
          <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="3"/>
          <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100"/>
          <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100"/>
          <!-- needed to highlight the searched term -->
          <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
          <!-- custom provider for getting an HTML excerpt in a query result with rep:excerpt() -->
          <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultXMLExcerpt"/>
    </SearchIndex> 
</Repository>
```

====================

Now here is my question. I am using tomcat9 where I have adde jackrabbit war to webapps and made it work.

In order to create cluster with let's say 3 nodes, do I have to have 3 different tomcats with 3 set of repositiory.xml with different Clusterids pointing to same datasource?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to create cluster with let's say 3 nodes, do I have to have 3 different tomcats with 3 set of repositiory.xml with different Clusterids pointing to same datasource?

In general yes, having N nodes set up with their own `repository.xml` and cluster id(Cluster section) using the same datasource will work.

Keep in mind that the following requirements must be met in order to use clustering.

Quoting from [official docs](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering) (Requirements section):

> - Each cluster node must have its own repository configuration.
> - A DataStore must always be shared between nodes, if used.
> - The global FileSystem on the repository level must be shared (only the one that is on the same level as the data store; only in the
>     repository.xml file).
> - Each cluster node needs its own (private) workspace level and version FileSystem (only those within the workspace and versioning
>     configuration; the ones in the repository.xml and workspace.xml file).
> - Each cluster node needs its own (private) Search indexes.
> - Every cluster node must be assigned a unique ID.
> - A journal type must be chosen, either based on files or stored in a database.
> - Each cluster node must use the same (shared) journal.
> - The persistence managers must store their data in the same, globally accessible location.